# Show equality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $A,B,C$ sets. Show that $(A \cup B ) \cup C=A \cup (B \cup C)$.

That's what I have tried:

$$x \in (A \cup B) \cup C \leftrightarrow  x \in A \cup B \vee x \in C \leftrightarrow x \in A \vee x \in B \vee x \in C \leftrightarrow x \in A \vee x \in B \cup C \leftrightarrow x \in A \cup(B \cup C)$$

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: It's fine,but using logical connectives in such a simple proof to me is overkill. Still,if it helps you while you're learning the ropes,by all means,go for it.

Comment: Nice... Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfect,I'm also a a few months into set theory,and this is how I had to prove it in my  homework.

Comment: Great... Thank you!!! :-)